# Site can't be reached when redirecting to crystal report page in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, crystal-reports

I am new to web application development to host in IIS.
I have developed a web application (ASP.Net Core Web App & .net 5.0 framework) using VS2019 which should render crystal reports.
As there is no support to crystal reports in ASP.Net Core 5.0, I added one more project **ASP.Net Crystal Reports Website** to my solution.

This solution is working perfectly in my development machine and in production machine.
But when I access the application from another system, all the functionalities of my main project are working.
But when loading crystal report page, I'm getting error "This site can't be reached. check if there is a typo in crystalreports"
I tried ip address in place of site name and allowed port numbers in Windows Firewall.

Please help me to resolve this issue

-Pancha

Comment: Can other pages except the Crystal Reports page be accessed normally? and do you get any other error messages? such as the consol.

Comment: I have two websites namely nbms & CrystalReports, deployed in IIS. Crystal Reports doesn't have other pages. When I access nbms from other PCs, it is working. When generating the reports, I redirect page to CrystalReports website's page. This is not working

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run the Crystal IIS app in a different app pool (like v4.0).